# which or what type water pump for car washing in remote location

Tags: water, pump

I want to be able to clean atvs and car in my garage at home. My garage is a couple of hundred feet from my home which has city water. Its too cost prohibitive to run water to garage for the little I would use it there. My plan is to have a 55 gallon drum in the garage to store the water and need to figure out what is the correct pump to use for adequate water delivery and pressure. It will run on 110 volts and use a 50 ft 5/8 hose with a spray nozzle. Im thinking a shallow well pump with a pressure tank but not sure what size is correct. Any input very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just run a long hose from the house? And are you looking for a pump to get water into the barrel (e.g. It's raised and you want to get water up into it) or to pump from the barrel to a hose you'll be holding in your hand?

Comment: If  I am following you correctly - you intend to fill and tote this 55 gallon drum - as you say it is too cost prohibitive to run the water to the garage ? IF the drum is in the garage the water needs to get into it somehow ..
Pvc Pipe is probably cheap enough to run 200 hundred feet or even a long rubber hose.. A few more details for clarity please .. you might might be working harder than you need to ..

Answer (score 1):

If your only objective is to wash vehicles, you may not need to get as elaborate as a well pump and storage/pressure tank. If you believe that 55 gallons is sufficient volume, it may be more cost effective to connect an inexpensive electric pressure washer to your 55 gallon drum and allow the pressure washer to provide delivery and force to the stream.

Most pressure washers will specify required volume of water in gallons per minute feed which would result in the need to measure your water flow through the hose. If it meets or exceeds the specifications, you would have few problems with accomplishing your objective.

[image: electric pressure washer]

I use an electric pressure washer on the end of a smaller hose. My house is on a well-pump system and it meets the specifications only when the pump is running, but the pressure washer continues to operate. Perhaps the specifications are conservative, or the washer reduces output, but the result is satisfactory to me.

Comment: Most consumer pressure washers rely on typical household water pressure feeding the input water.  To operate them from a tank normally requires a small feed pump.  Otherwise, the input water won't keep up with the pressure washer and the pressure washer will have a short life.